# Css3 animation by Javascript: Scale and transition after

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have html code:

```
<img id="img" src="http://piximus.net/media/9307/thumb.jpg" width="50" />
```

And Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $("#img").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "left top")
   $("#img").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1, 3)")
   $("#img").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 5s linear")
});
```

I wanna see: scaled(dynamically) image immediately and set "-webkit-transition" for further changes. (For example: scale(1, 3)=>scale(3, 1))
But work like:

```
$("#img").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 5s linear")
$("#img").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1, 3)")
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/B4cxq/2/

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a new css property when the transition on the element #img is completed.
This can be done by registering to the transition end events. See the code below

```
$(function() {
    $("#img").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "left top")

    $("#img").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 5s linear")
    $("#img").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        $("#img").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(3, 1)")
    });

    $("#img").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1, 3)")

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But 5s! Minimum duration is 0.1s for event(transitionend).
But flicking visible.